# iOS app - storage method for local html

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, uiwebview, plist

I am using UIWebView to display HTML, at the moment I have hard coded the HTML like so:

```
NSString *data = @"<body style='border:5px solid silver;'><h1>hello</h1><ul><li>gfhgf</li></ul><img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c2/Tron_Legacy_poster.jpg'/></body>";
```

However, I would now like to know how to store the HTML using a more practical and maintainable method as I will be serving HTML intensive data per view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store it as a file in the bundle.  You can read it using a local NSURLRequest.  There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to do this.